# Can this generalization of the exponential function be expressed using more familiar functions?

Tags: calculus, power-series, special-functions, elementary-functions

For each $n \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq -1}$, define:

$$\exp_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{\prod_{j=1}^i(j+n)} = 1 + \frac{x}{1+n}+\frac{x^2}{(1+n)(2+n)}+\cdots$$

Note that the $n=0$ case corresponds to the familiar exponential function.

> **Question.** Can this generalization of the exponential function be expressed using more familiar functions?

I'm mainly interested in the case $n \in \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$

Comment: @tired, the denominator doesn't equal $(i+n)!.$ It does equal $(i+n)^{\downarrow i}$, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Pochhamer symbols $$\prod_{j=1}^i(j+n)=(n+1)_i$$ which make $$\exp_n(x)=\frac{e^x}{ x^{n}}\, \left(\Gamma (n+1)-n\, \Gamma (n,x)\right)$$ where appear the complete and incomplete gamma functions.

Comment: Thanks. Can this be done more simply with the lower incomplete gamma function? I'm staring at the expression $$e^x x^{-s}\gamma(s,x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\prod_{j=0}^i(s+j)}$$ and just wondering how to tinker with it to change the $j=0$ into a $j=1$.

Comment: @goblin. I suppose that $x^k$ stands for $x^i$. If you start at $j=0$, the result is effectively $\frac{e^x x^{-s} (\Gamma (s+1)-s \Gamma (s,x))}{s}$. I do not think that you could avoid the gamma function.